# My cURL request does not create cookie on my PHP page

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm starting now with cURL and came across a problem:
I am trying to make a simple request for a page in another domain.

This page contains the following content to create a simple cookie.

**test.php**

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    setcookie("TestCookie", "newcookie");
?>
```

First I made the request for this page via ajax as follows:

```
<!-- Simple ajax request -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> <!-- Jquery -->

<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com/test/test.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
</script>
```

When I ran the code above the cookie was normally created on my browser.

[image]

Then I tried to do the same task with cURL with the following code:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/test/test.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

But when I execute the above code nothing happens so no error message is returned and Here comes my doubts:

> What are the differences between requests made between cURL and AJAX? do they serve the same purpose? when to use one and when to use another?And why via curl the cookie was not created? Is it something wrong with the code or is it a specific feature of curl?

I hope I have been clear in my questions, as I am starting some concepts are not yet very clear to me, thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the differences between requests made between cURL and AJAX?

cURL, the way you use it, allows you to make an HTTP request from the PHP program (running on the server).

Ajax is a term given to making an HTTP request from JavaScript (running in the browser).

> when to use one and when to use another?

Use Ajax when the browser needs to communicate with a URL. Use PHP when the server needs to communicate with a URL.

> And why via curl the cookie was not created?

Because the browser didn't make the HTTP request, so it didn't get the HTTP response with the `Set-Cookie` header.